# Issue with radius search?

Tags: elasticsearch

We're on Elasticsearch 1.3.2.

We can't seem to get a record returned when doing a radial search against a linestring.

Our mapping can be broken down to this:

```
{
   "simpleline":{
        "properties": { 
            "geo_linestring": {
                 "type": "geo_shape",
                 "tree": "quadtree",
                 "tree_levels": 26
             }
         } 
    }
}
```

We have a linear path that sort of forms a "U":

```
{
    "geo_linestring": {
        "type": "linestring",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                -96.6906661987305,
                47.7989692687988
            ],
            [
                -96.7057800292969,
                47.2933502197266
            ],
            [
                -96.3336181640625,
                47.2952117919922
            ],
            [
                -96.3226318359375,
                47.8358612060547
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

The connection between middle two points appear to be within 15-20 miles of the city of Felton, MN. So, if we wanted to find all "trails" within 30 miles of Felton, we want this to appear.

However, filtering on a circle centered at Felton (30 mile radius) does not return the item. Increasing the radius to 40 miles, however, does:

```
{
    "filter": {
        "geo_shape": {
            "geo_linestring": {
                "shape": {
                    "type": "circle",
                    "radius": "30mi",
                    "coordinates": [
                        -96.5055999755859,
                        47.0751991271973
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Are we just misunderstanding how this search works, or is there an issue with how we're approaching this?